# LSM9DS1 magnetometer fast ODR and Self-test modes

Tags: magnetometer

The datasheet of the [LSM9DS1](https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/1639232/0/0/1/LSM9DS1-Datasheet.pdf) says on the page 63:

```
CTRL_REG1_M (20h)

FAST_ODR - Enables data rates higher than 80 Hz. Default value: 0
(0: Fast_ODR disabled; 1: FAST_ODR enabled)

ST - Self-test enable. Default value: 0
(0: self-test disabled; 1: self-test enabled)
```

Unfortunately, there is nothing else in the datasheet about these modes.

What data rate(s) will take place once the `FAST_ODR` will be enabled? How is that related to the `DO` field in the CTRL_REG1_M (20h)?

What is self-test? How can I know its result? Does it run constantly in the background? Etc.